# How to integrate a function with respect to the logarithm of a variable?

Tags: integration, substitution

I am having trouble integrating the equation $\frac{dN}{dlogM} = C\left(\frac{M}{M_{br}}\right)^n$. I just need it between two limits, say $M_{l}$ and $M_{h}$. Sorry for a remedial question, it has been a long time since I have had to do something like this (if I have in the past). How do I convert the limits/the function? These are all $\log_{10}$, not natural logs.

Here is where I am at:

$
N = \int_{M_{l}}^{M_{h}} C \left(\frac{M}{M_{br}}\right)^n dlogM
$

Substitute $\frac{d\log_{10}M}{dM} =\frac{1}{M\ln10}$

$
N = \int_{M_{l}}^{M_{h}} C \left(\frac{M}{M_{br}}\right)^n \frac{1}{M\ln 10}dM.
$

Then some simplifying and solving. Am I wrong anywhere? Do I need to do anything to the limits ($M_h,M_l$)? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: the integrand is proportional to $M^{n-1}$. You don't have to change the limits if they're values of $M$.

Comment: @J.G. Thank you! It seems like I haven't messed anything up? I can figure out the integral from where I left it, just want to be sure I didn't go astray somewhere. Thank you for confirming on the limits, that is helpful!